# Quartz scheduler deadlock on creating triggers/jobs in qrtz tables

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

Am creating a main cronjob for a scheduled time, from that job am creating 10 simpletrigger jobs without delay and for each simpletriger job am creating another set of 100 jobs.

Am using spring and my thread pool size is 30, am using h2 database, JobStoreTX, StdJDBCDelegate for database connection. My app is an standalone java program which initiates the main job.

It created the first set of jobdetail/ trigger detail in the qrtz tables. when it executes the first simple job spanning sub job's got a table lock on trigger and job entries.

What might be the issue?

Exception is :
"Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Deadlock detected. The current transaction was rolled back. Details: "
Session #64 (user: SA) is waiting to lock PUBLIC.QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS while locking PUBLIC.QRTZ_TRIGGERS (exclusive).
Session #67 (user: SA) is waiting to lock PUBLIC.QRTZ_TRIGGERS while locking PUBLIC.QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS (exclusive)."; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO qrtz_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS (TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, REPEAT_COUNT, REPEAT_INTERVAL, TIMES_TRIGGERED)  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [40001-132]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:316)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.doLock(RegularTable.java:435)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.lock(RegularTable.java:382)"

Comment: Having issue will concurrent triggers and job, a main trigger is going to completed before its child triggers and jobs finishing its task.And another question if my thread pool count in quartz is 30 that means i should have only 30 jobs in the pool or it denotes the running jobs count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using mvcc mode of H2 - which is required (as far as I understand it) for row locking to be enabled, rather than table locking? (much like the difference between MySQL with and without InnoDB).

http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUARTZ-773